# How can I disable many2many_tags widget from having create and edit?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I have something like this:

```
<tree string="Lines" editable="bottom">
 <field name="required_weekday" widget="many2many_tags"/>
</tree>
```

When I edit the `many2many_tags` has a create and edit option. But since I'm dealing with weekdays I just have a pre-populated model and there's no need to add additional ones. How can I disable create and edit?

Comment: I think you should use it as selecton

Answer (score 0):

Try this module [web_m2x_options](https://github.com/0k/web_m2x_options)

Answer (score 0):

Just make your field look like this on your XML:

```
<field name="your_field" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create_edit': True}"/>
```